# Unvaccinated children/teens and self-isolation when entering New Zealand

Tags: covid-19, new-zealand, quarantine, new-zealand-citizens

We are looking at visiting New Zealand now that the NZ government has released their plan to reopen the border.  The current info says that fully vaccinated eligible travelers can self-isolate when entering NZ (rather than using MIQ) from March 14 (or Feb 28 if traveling from Oz).

What I can't find on the [Entering New Zealand in 2022](https://www.miq.govt.nz/travel-to-new-zealand/entering-new-zealand-in-2022/) website is information on whether children need to be fully vaccinated, or whether we will still need to enter MIQ because some of our children are not vaccinated.

If a family has unvaccinated children, must they still use MIQ to enter NZ from March 2022?

We are NZ citizens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would call the NZ immigration helpline and ask them, but if they are following a similar path to the current requirements then children under the age of 17 are exempt.

> The requirement will not apply to New Zealand citizens, children under the age of 17, and those who are unable to be vaccinated for medical reasons.

https://www.miq.govt.nz/travel-to-new-zealand/plan-your-travel-to-nz/overseas-vaccinations/

Comment: +1 thanks, that gives me something to start with.  The problem I see is that this isn't an exemption from MIQ, just the requirement to be vaccinated.  If my kids are unvaccinated (exempted here) then they (or we) may still need to enter MIQ.  I will see if I can find a way to contact INZ

Comment: I received a reply back (from "Unite against COVID-19") that agrees with your answer and gave a link https://covid19.govt.nz/international-travel/travel-to-new-zealand/when-new-zealand-borders-open/#self-isolation-requirements . Our 17yo will need to be vaccinated in order to self-isolate, the younger children are exempt and can self-isolate with the parents